# Detect when an element is done loading new HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have a load event in another js file, which uses .on('load') to load in new HTML when clicking on pagination. However, I need something to happen in another script once that html is done loaded. So far I've tried this, but no luck. js-ajax-content-container is the element that is loading in new HTML. js-ajax-link is the pagination link I click to initiate the load event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.js-ajax-link', function() {
  $('body').on('.js-ajax-content-container', 'ajaxComplete', function() {
    alert("loaded");
  });
});
```

Comment: There most likely is no event for this, you have to actually trigger something in the success callback for the first ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire a custom event in one script and listen to it in another.

*By the way, your arguments are in the wrong order for `on()`.

First you pass the event name and then the selector.*

```
$('body').on('click', '.js-ajax-link', function() {
  $('body').on('ajaxComplete','.js-ajax-content-container', function() {
    $(document).trigger('ajaxLinkLoaded');
  });
});
```

And in another script you can listen to this event:

```
$(document).on('ajaxLinkLoaded', function(e){ // do something});
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That is incredibly helpful. I didn't realize you could attach triggers do the document. I imagine I will be using this often in the future. Also, oops about the ordering...I knew that just tired haha...You'll see I even got it right the line above.